# Using dot notation to access CLOS slots

Tags: common-lisp, clos

When accessing class slots, instead of writing

```
(defmethod get-name ((somebody person) (slot-value somebody 'name))
```

is it possible to use the dot notation aka C++, namely

```
(defmethod get-name ((somebody person) somebody.name) ?
```

Otherwise, when there are many slot operations in a method, `(slot-value...` creates a lot of boilerplate code.

I have figured out the answer today and I am just posting it as a Q&A, but if there are better solutions or there are problems I should expect with my solution, feel free to add new answers or comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not write accessors by hand, nor use `slot-value` (outside of object lifecycle functions, where the accessors may not have been created yet).  Use the class slot options instead:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((name :reader foo-name
         :initarg :name)
   (bar :accessor foo-bar
        :initarg :bar)))
```

Now you can use the named accessors:

```
(defun example (some-foo new-bar)
  (let ((n (foo-name some-foo))
        (old-bar (foo-bar some-foo)))
    (setf (foo-bar some-foo) new-bar)
    (values n old-bar)))
```

Often, you want your classes to be "immutable", you'd use `:reader` instead of `:accessor` then, which only creates the reader, not the setf expansion.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed what I was looking for. I guess I just didn't read the respective chapter in Practical Common Lisp far enough :) So I also did not know that there are with-slots and with-accessors macros.

Answer (score 6):

The library [access](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/access) provides a dot notation reader macro for accessing slots (and hash-tables and other things). After enabling the reader macro by calling (access:enable-dot-syntax) you'll able to use #D. to access a slot name with the dot syntax popular in other languages.

```
(defclass person ()
  ((name :initarg :name :reader name)))

CL-USER> (access:enable-dot-syntax)
; No values
CL-USER> (defvar *foo* (make-instance 'person :name "John Smith"))
*FOO*
CL-USER> #D*foo*
#<PERSON #x302001F1E5CD>
CL-USER> #D*foo*.name
"John Smith"
```

There is also a `with-dot` macro if you don't want to use a reader macro

```
CL-USER> (access:with-dot () *foo*.name)
"John Smith"
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this library. Unfortunately, I cannot try it right now, (ql:quickload "access") results in errors (I will be hard pressed to remember the last time that pacman -S resulted in an error). I'll get back to your answer once I resolve those.

Comment: Apparently, there were some issues with forward compatibility. Updating all packages with (ql:update-all-dists) solved the issue and I can try the access library now. I like it because, well, it is a library and I don't need to code and maintain anything myself. I like it less for the task at hand. The focus of the library is different than simply providing a dot notation for classes and it does a lot of runtime checks. Accessing a slot of an object is 149 time slower than my manual approach, and accessing a slot of a slot of an object is 174 times slower.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solutions seems to be a reader macro that overloads `.` so that `(slot-value somebody 'name)` can be written as `.somebody.name` My strategy is to read `somebody.name` as a string (we need to define a non-terminating macro character so that the reader does not stop mid-string), and then process the string to construct the appropriate `(slot-value...`

I will need two helper functions:

```
(defun get-symbol (str)
  "Make an uppercase symbol"
  (intern (string-upcase str)))

(defun split-string (str sep &optional (start 0))
  "Split a string into lists given a character separator"
  (let ((end (position sep str :start start)))
    (cons (subseq str start end) (if end (split-string str sep (1+ end))))))
```

And then I can define my reader macro:

```
(defun dot-reader (stream char)
  (declare (ignore char))
  (labels ((make-query (list)
             (let ((car (car list))
                   (cdr (cdr list)))
               (if cdr `(slot-value ,(make-query cdr) (quote ,(get-symbol car)))
                   (get-symbol car)))))
    (make-query (nreverse (split-string (symbol-name (read stream)) #\.)))))
```

Finally, I need to register this reader macro:

```
(set-macro-character #\. #'dot-reader t)
```

Now it is possible to write:

```
(defmethod get-name ((somebody person) .somebody.name)
```

or, if `name` is itself a class,

```
(defmethod get-name ((somebody person) .somebody.name.first-name)
```

One restriction is that s-expressions will not work between the dots, say

```
.(get-my-class).name
```

won't work.

Comment: Does this still allow the normal consing dot, e.g. `(setq cons '(a . b))`?

Comment: @Barmar Interesting point but yes, consing dot still works. It seams the reader macro is simply not called in this case.